# Why my testNG test gets java.lang.OutOfMemoryError

Tags: java, exception, testng

I create a simple testNG test, it doesn't work and throws OutOfMemoryError. I cannot find the cause.

What I've done:

I calculate the size of this big double array, and it's about 76MB which is less than the max heap size. I think the cause is in testNG. I'm not clear about how testNG pass the parameter (I checked the exception trace and found there was a char array copy, it confused me). I've searched a lot about "How testNG pass parameter" via google but don't get some useful info. So any one can help to point out the root cause, thank you.

Environment:

```
Yosemite 10.10
Java 1.8.0_25
Eclipse luna 4.4.1
-XX:MaxPermSize=256m
-Xms40m
-Xmx512m
```

Code:

```
import java.util.Arrays;
import org.testng.annotations.DataProvider;
import org.testng.annotations.Test;

public class TestNGTest {
    static int ARRAY_SIZE = 10000000;

    @DataProvider(name = "array to sort")
    public static Object[][] arrayProvider() {
        double[] myArray = new double[ARRAY_SIZE];
        for (int i = 0; i < ARRAY_SIZE; i++) {
            myArray[i] = Math.random();
        }
        return new Object[][] { { myArray } };
    }

    @Test(dataProvider = "array to sort")
    public void testSort(double[] array) {
        Arrays.sort(array);
    }

}
```

Result:

```
FAILED: testSort
java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
at java.util.Arrays.copyOf(Arrays.java:3332)
at java.lang.AbstractStringBuilder.expandCapacity(AbstractStringBuilder.java:137)
at java.lang.AbstractStringBuilder.ensureCapacityInternal(AbstractStringBuilder.java:121)
at java.lang.AbstractStringBuilder.append(AbstractStringBuilder.java:421)
at java.lang.StringBuilder.append(StringBuilder.java:136)
at org.testng.remote.strprotocol.TestResultMessage.toString(TestResultMessage.java:320)
at org.testng.remote.strprotocol.TestResultMessage.<init>(TestResultMessage.java:106)
at org.testng.remote.strprotocol.TestResultMessage.<init>(TestResultMessage.java:124)
at org.testng.remote.strprotocol.RemoteTestListener.onTestFailure(RemoteTestListener.java:72)
at org.testng.internal.Invoker.runTestListeners(Invoker.java:1895)
at org.testng.internal.Invoker.runTestListeners(Invoker.java:1879)
at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeMethod(Invoker.java:778)
at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeTestMethod(Invoker.java:901)
at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeTestMethods(Invoker.java:1231)
at org.testng.internal.TestMethodWorker.invokeTestMethods(TestMethodWorker.java:127)
at org.testng.internal.TestMethodWorker.run(TestMethodWorker.java:111)
at org.testng.TestRunner.privateRun(TestRunner.java:767)
at org.testng.TestRunner.run(TestRunner.java:617)
at org.testng.SuiteRunner.runTest(SuiteRunner.java:334)
at org.testng.SuiteRunner.runSequentially(SuiteRunner.java:329)
at org.testng.SuiteRunner.privateRun(SuiteRunner.java:291)
at org.testng.SuiteRunner.run(SuiteRunner.java:240)
at org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.runSuite(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:52)
at org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.run(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:86)
at org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesSequentially(TestNG.java:1224)
at org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesLocally(TestNG.java:1149)
at org.testng.TestNG.run(TestNG.java:1057)
at org.testng.remote.RemoteTestNG.run(RemoteTestNG.java:111)
at org.testng.remote.RemoteTestNG.initAndRun(RemoteTestNG.java:204)
at org.testng.remote.RemoteTestNG.main(RemoteTestNG.java:175)
```

Comment: How are you executing? From Eclipse?

Comment: Yes, run from Eclipse.

Comment: `public int arraysize` value is crying out for OutOfMemory error. I am not surprised that you are getting it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is indeed likely to be TestNG, although to be absolutely sure we'd need to see more of the stack trace.

While generating the report, TestNG probably tries to convert your array to string, to use it as the name of your test case.

The easiest solution (apart from not using gigantic arrays in a unit test) is to wrap the array in an object which has a simple `toString()` method that doesn't require printing the entire array.

Comment: That actually sounds extremely likely.